# Weather Underground widget for Linux?

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm looking for a Linux gnome widget that can display data from a nearby Weather Undergound station. Does anybody know of something like that? I can program if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Gdesklets](http://www.gdesklets.de/) and you can find lot of widgets for this [here](http://www.gdesklets.de/index.php?q=desklet/browse/category/101)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Gnome-Do and add the "weather docklet".